A question about inducing of group representations
Let $G$ be a compact Lie group, $K$ its closed subgroup, $\rho$ a finite-dimensional real irreducible representation of $K$, $c\rho$ its complexification, $\mathrm{Ind}^G_K(\rho)$
the real representation of $G$ induced by $\rho$. My question is as follows: is the representation $\mathrm{Ind}^G_K(\rho)$ induced by $c\rho$ equivalent to the complexification $c\mathrm{Ind}^G_K(\rho)$ of the induced representation $\mathrm{Ind}^G_K(\rho)$?
